# How can I remove patterns using sed command in a file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, command-line, files

I have a document and I want to remove all the patterns so that I stay with only some information, the producer/creator of that document.

I managed to replace patterns with one word "PATTERN" so that it becomes easy to remove them. How can I remove this word? Here are the commands I used:

```
$ cat /path | tr \n \f | \
  tr -cd "[A-Za-z0-9 () /\f] | \
  sed s/stream.*endstream/STREAM/ | sed s/[0-9][0-9]* /PATTERN/g | \
  sed "s/PATTERN PATTERN n/PTR/g"
```

I obtain this

> /rdfRDF/xxmpmetaxpacket efdwefdstreamefdobjPATTERN PATTERN
>   obj/DisplayDocTitle trueefdobjPATTERN PATTERN obj/Type/XRef/Size
>   PATTERN/W[ PATTERN PATTERN PATTERN] /Root PATTERN PATTERN R/Iffo
>   PATTERN PATTERN
>   R/ID[PATTERNFEFPATTERNCPATTERNEPATTERNDBPATTERNFPATTERNEPATTERNFPATTERNEEPATTERNFEFPATTERNCPATTERNEPATTERNDBPATTERNFPATTERNEPATTERNFPATTERNEEPATTERN]
>   /Filter/FlateDecode/Lefgth PATTERNstreamxc
>   Z)PATTERNBSekgPBB(FUfLqSuefdstreamefdobjxrefPATTERN PATTERN PATTERN
>   fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN
>   fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN
>   fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN
>   fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN
>   fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN
>   fPATTERN PATTERN fPATTERN PATTERN ftrailer/Size PATTERN/Root PATTERN
>   PATTERN R/Iffo PATTERN PATTERN
>   R/ID[PATTERNFEFPATTERNCPATTERNEPATTERNDBPATTERNFPATTERNEPATTERNFPATTERNEEPATTERNFEFPATTERNCPATTERNEPATTERNDBPATTERNFPATTERNEPATTERNFPATTERNEEPATTERN]
>   startxrefPATTERNEOFxrefPATTERN PATTERNtrailer/Size PATTERN/Root
>   PATTERN PATTERN R/Iffo PATTERN PATTERN
>   R/ID[PATTERNFEFPATTERNCPATTERNEPATTERNDBPATTERNFPATTERNEPATTERNFPATTERNEEPATTERNFEFPATTERNCPATTERNEPATTERNDBPATTERNFPATTERNEPATTERNFPATTERNEEPATTERN]
>   /Prev PATTERN/XRefStm PATTERNstartxrefPATTERNEOF

How to remove the word PATTERN?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).   What are you actually trying to do?   Is the input data an [RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) file?  if not, what is it?

Comment: you probably want to use [exempi](https://libopenraw.pages.freedesktop.org/exempi/) - this is a program designed for working with [XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform)  data on the command line.   e.g. you can use `exempi -g <foo>` to extract the value of an XMP property called "foo".   I expect your difficulties are an object lesson in why you shouldn't try to process structured data like XML without using a proper parser (i.e. don't use only regexps to process XML).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sed -i -e 's/PATTERN//g' filename
```

From man page:

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

   -e script, --expression=script
          add the script to the commands to be executed
```

Comment: That is helpful, thanks. However, it seems that I also removed the producer of the document in my previous commands -$ cat /path | tr \n \f |tr -cd "[A-Za-z0-9 () /\f] | sed s/stream.endstream/STREAM/ | sed s/[0-9][0-9] /PATTERN/g | sed "s/PATTERN PATTERN n/PTR/g".

Comment: How can I remove something like ((((((((((((((QEQEQEQEQEW using the sed command?

Comment: @Lionel I have tried the following and it seems to work: `sed -i -re 's/[(][(][(][(][(][(][(][(][(][(][(][(][(][(]QEQEQEQEQEW//g' filename`